# Creating keywords which have an associated **end** with algorithm2e

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

As a part of a homework assignment in a Latex course, I have been assigned to write this algorithm in Latex.
[image: AdaBoost Algorithm]

I have got most of the part done with this code:-

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, blindtext}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \RestyleAlgo{boxed}
    \begin{algorithm}[h!]
        \DontPrintSemicolon
        \SetKwInput{kwInput}{Input}
        \SetKwInput{kwInit}{Initialization}
        \SetKwInput{kwMain}{Forward Inclusion}
        \SetKwInput{kwOutput}{Output}
        \kwInput{
        \par
        \vspace{0.25cm}
            Training examples $ Z = \{(x_1 , y_1 ), . . . , (x_N , y_N )\} $, where $N = a + b$, of which $a$ examples have $y_i = 1$ and $b$ examples have $ y_i = −1 $\;
            \vspace{0.25cm}
            The number $M$ of weak classifiers to be combined.

        }
        \kwInit{
        \par
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \Indp{
            $
                w_i^{(0)}= \begin{cases}
                    \frac{1}{2a} & \text{$for\ those\ examples\ with\ y_i=1$} \\
                    \frac{1}{2b} & \text{$otherwise$}
                \end{cases}
            $
        }
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        }
        \kwMain{
        \par
        \vspace{0.25cm}
            \For{m = 1, . . . , M}{
                Choose optimal $h_m$ to minimize the weighted error\;
                Choose $a_m$ according to (2.17)\;
                Update $w_i^{(m)} \gets w_i^{(m-1)} e^{-y_ia_mh_m(x_i)}$ and normalize to $\sum_i{w_i^{(m)}} = 1$\;
            }
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        }
        \kwOutput{
        \par
            Classification Function: $H_M(x)$ as in (2.20)\;
            Class Label Prediction: $\hat{y}(x) = sgn(H_M(x))$\;
        }
        \caption{AdaBoost Learning Algorithm [35]}
    \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

However, I am unable to create a new Keyword (Like `\kwInit` in the code above) which has its own associated **end**, and auto-indented code segment.

Being new to the Latex typesetting system, any help is highly welcome.

For reference, my code produces output that looks like this:-

[image: My AdaBoost Latex Code O/p]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the `\SetKwInput{word}` with `\SetKwBlock{beginword}{endword}`.
See `algorithm2e`[manual](https://ctan.crest.fr/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) Section 11.2 page 35.
This modification provides

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, blindtext}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \RestyleAlgo{boxed}
    \begin{algorithm}[h!]
        \DontPrintSemicolon
        \SetKwInput{kwInput}{Input}
        \SetKwBlock{kwInit}{Initialization}{end}
        \SetKwBlock{kwMain}{Forward Inclusion}{end}
        \SetKwInput{kwOutput}{Output}
        \kwInput{
        \par
        \vspace{0.25cm}
            Training examples $ Z = \{(x_1 , y_1 ), . . . , (x_N , y_N )\} $, where $N = a + b$, of which $a$ examples have $y_i = 1$ and $b$ examples have $ y_i = −1 $\;
            \vspace{0.25cm}
            The number $M$ of weak classifiers to be combined.

        }
        \kwInit{
        \par
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        \Indp{
            $
                w_i^{(0)}= \begin{cases}
                    \frac{1}{2a} & \text{$for\ those\ examples\ with\ y_i=1$} \\
                    \frac{1}{2b} & \text{$otherwise$}
                \end{cases}
            $
        }
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        }
        \kwMain{
        \par
        \vspace{0.25cm}
            \For{m = 1, . . . , M}{
                Choose optimal $h_m$ to minimize the weighted error\;
                Choose $a_m$ according to (2.17)\;
                Update $w_i^{(m)} \gets w_i^{(m-1)} e^{-y_ia_mh_m(x_i)}$ and normalize to $\sum_i{w_i^{(m)}} = 1$\;
            }
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        }
        \kwOutput{
        \par
            Classification Function: $H_M(x)$ as in (2.20)\;
            Class Label Prediction: $\hat{y}(x) = sgn(H_M(x))$\;
        }
        \caption{AdaBoost Learning Algorithm [35]}
    \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have been stuck for hours trying to wade through the docs for this. P.S. You've put my code and your output in the answer ;)

Comment: @saketk21 Happy to help, this is the very purpose of this place. I corrected the code.